# Change state of Dynamically created toggle button to on and off on Another clicking button

Tags: android

I need to create a toogle button dynamically & on clicking a button all the toggle button should be change to default state.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pref_Array.length; i++) {
                 ToggleButton tglPreference = new ToggleButton(this);
                tglPreference.setId(i);
                tglPreference.setTextSize(20);
                tglPreference.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_toggle);
                tglPreference
                        .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tglPreference.setTextOn("On);
                tglPreference.setTextOff("OFF);
}


btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: did u tired toggleButton.setchecked(true or false)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

Enter getTag/setTag:

```
button1.setTag(1);
button2.setTag(2);
```

Now we can use the same OnClickListener for every button:

```
listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doAction(v.getTag());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your ToggleButtons in an `ArrayList` for later access.

```
List<ToggleButton> toggleButtons = new ArrayList<ToggleButton>();

for (int i = 0; i < pref_Array.length; i++) {
    ToggleButton tglPreference = new ToggleButton(this);
    tglPreference.setId(i);
    tglPreference.setTextSize(20);
    tglPreference.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_toggle);
    tglPreference
        .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tglPreference.setTextOn("On);
    tglPreference.setTextOff("OFF);
    toggleButtons.add(tglPreference);
}
```

Then in your buttons onClickListener...

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for ( ToggleButton button : toggleButtons ) {
                  // set button to default state....
            }
        }
    });
```